# Is there indentation in org src blocks?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python, indentation

I'm going kinda crazy trying to understand what's going on here... Asked [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/qldige/is_there_indentation_in_org_source_blocks/?ref=share&ref_source=link) on the r/emacs subreddit so apologies if any of you are seeing this again.

Do org blocks allow `TAB` indentation without going into special editing mode via `C-c '`  ?

I have the following relevant settings in my `custom-set-variables` block (i.e. edited via `customize-mode`.

```
 '(org-edit-src-content-indentation 0)
 '(org-src-preserve-indentation nil)
```

I used these settings because I was getting sick of editing code in the source block and having all the lines jump 2 spaces to the right.

`org-src-tab-acts-natively` is set to `t` as well.

But now when I write

```
#+begin_src python
def hello():
|
#+end_src
```

the cursor is stuck at the start of the line and I can't use `TAB` to indent to add a new line, i.e. to *make it look like*:

```
def hello( ):
    print("hello)
```

`TAB` **used** to work -- or atleast, I thought it was working. [This github comment](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7458#issuecomment-254430710) suggests that this facility was never actually available, and we always had to use `C-c '` to edit code properly. But then [this Stackoverflow post and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26455179/10040168), as well as [this github issue](https://github.com/alex-hhh/emacs-sql-indent/issues/96) seem to imply otherwise.

Now, I have also set `org-adapt-indentation` to `nil`, because I prefer org-headings, sub-headings and text to be aligned with the buffer edge. If I set it to `1`, it looks like there is some aligning going on when I hit `TAB`, but this is not perfect. Does this explain the "pseudo-indenting" that I had before, and there really is no inherent `TAB` indent in org blocks?

I have also been recommended `poly-mode` and `poly-org`, but I'd first like to understand what is going on here.

**EDIT**: I have neglected to say that the message `Can’t guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: 4` appears in the minibuffer after each failed `TAB` press. I wouldn't have thought that would be the difference, as long as it guessed a non-zero offset.

**EDIT:** `Org mode version 9.4.4 (release_9.4.4 @ /usr/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/org/)`

**EDIT:** Here is the tab-indentation behavior when running `emacs -Q` https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm05v.jpg

Comment: What is the value of `org-cycle-emulate-tab`? If `nil`, set it to `t` and try again. Check the doc string of the variable with `C-h v org-cycle-emulate-tab`.

Comment: To avoid getting the message ```Can't guess ...``` add this to your python configuration: ```(setq python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose nil)```. Take care also to init ```tab-width``` to 4 and config ```python-indent-offset``` also to 4.

Answer (score 3):

`TAB` is bound to `org-cycle` in Org mode buffers: that function generally cycles the element that the cursor is on (headlines, drawers, source blocks) between the folded and unfolded state. But Org mode makes use of context-dependent bindings very often and that confuses things. E.g. in this case, *if* the cursor is in a table, the table is realigned and the cursor moves to the next cell.

But when the cursor is not on anything that `org-cycle` considers "special" to do something interesting, then it just executes the global binding of `TAB` which re-indents lines, *assuming that `org-cycle-emulate-tab` is not `nil`*. In that case, `TAB` *in* your python source code block (as opposed on the `#+BEGIN_SRC` line which folds the code block) should indent using `indent-for-tab-command` (unless you have modified the global binding of `TAB`).

EDIT: for debugging, try  adding and evaluating the following source block to an Org mode file:

```el
#+begin_src elisp
(global-key-binding (kbd "TAB"))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: indent-for-tab-command
```

Do you get `indent-for-tab-command` as the result? If so, go to your python source block and say `M-x indent-for-tab-command` - do you get the indentation you expect?

<s>EDIT 2: Note that you should not expect "real" python indentation. This is more like typing python code in a buffer that is in fundamental mode.</s>

EDIT 3: I stand corrected: you *should* expect "real" python indentation: `indent-for-tab-command` calls the function which is the value of the variable `indent-line-function`. Now inside an Org mode buffer, the value of that variable is `org-indent-line`, which, in source code blocks, calls `org-babel-do-key-sequence-in-edit-buffer`; that in turn calls the macro `org-babel-do-in-edit-buffer`: that finally calls whatever function is bound to `TAB` in the context of an edit buffer created by `org-edit-src-code` and then does `org-edit-src-exit` - phew! That's basically what would happen interactively, if you did `C-c '` in the source block, typed a `TAB` in the resulting source buffer (which is in python mode!) and then exited with another `C-c '`. But note that using two tabs to unindent, as would happen if you did it interactively, does not work: each tab is treated separately, so we go into the source buffer twice, do a single tab each time and exit. There are limitations to this approach.

Comment: Thanks -- it was `nil`, but setting `org-cycle-emulate-tab` to `t` (i.e. "Everywhere except in headlines") still does not fix this (even if I change `org-src-preserve-indentation`. Presumably indentation works for you, and properly (i.e. the tab does 4 spaces rather than whatever `org-edit-src-content-indentation` is set to)? Perhaps I need to do `emacs -Q` again and see if some other mode is hogging `TAB`, though I can't see which one.

Comment: I get two spaces on the first line and four additional spaces on subsequent lines, but N.B. this is more or less an accident: it's what you would get say if you tried typing python code in a buffer that is in Fundamental mode. You cannot expect it to do what "real" indentation would do in a python mode buffer.

Comment: I added some debugging suggestions, as well as the caveat from the previous comment to the answer.

Comment: I do get `indent-for-tab-command` when I evaluate that code block and running `M-x indent-for-tab-command` has the same result as using `TAB` -- no indent. However, I think I have neglected to say that the message `Can’t guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: 4` appears in the minibuffer each time. I wouldn't have thought that would be the difference, as long as it guessed a non-zero offset.

Comment: Re: "you should not expect "real" python indentation",  OK, but I would have thought having the variable `org-src-tab-acts-natively` would allow this to be the case, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26455179/10040168) and the `*Help*` page suggests. In any case, just a naive/`fundamental-mode` style indentation via `TAB` seems beyond me at the moment.

Comment: I get that message too, but it still indents. Did you try with `emacs -q`? As for `org-src-tab-acts-natively`, I have mine set to `t` but I don't really understand what it is supposed to do. I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131142/discussion-between-nonreligious-and-nickd).